# CGContextRef getting corrupted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My program is crashing when I call the function CGContextStrokePath (last line in the code below.) Can context get corrupted somehow?  (it only crashes when `expression` (which is an NSArray) has certain values in it). It's supposed to draw a graph of whatever is in `expression`. For example if `expression` has the objects: x, cos (represented as strings) it will draw a cosine curve. Here is the code:

```
- (double) yValueFromExpression:(id)anExpression atPosition:(double)xValue
{
    NSDictionary *aDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:xValue] forKey:@"%x"];
    return [CalculatorBrain evaluateExpression:anExpression usingVariableValues:aDictionary];
}

#define PRECISION 500

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    double scale = [self.delegate scaleForGraphView:self];
    id expression = [self.delegate expressionForGraphView:self];

    CGPoint origin; 
    origin.x = (self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width) / 2;
    origin.y = (self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height) / 2;

    [AxesDrawer drawAxesInRect:self.bounds originAtPoint:origin scale:scale];

    // -150/scale to 150/scale is the range of x values that axesDrawer (drawAxesInRect) displays.
    double leftMostXValue = -150 / scale;
    double rightMostXValue = 150 / scale;
    double increment = (rightMostXValue - leftMostXValue) / PRECISION;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, origin.y - 
                     [self yValueFromExpression:expression atPosition:leftMostXValue] * scale); 

    for (int i = 1; i <= PRECISION; ++i) {
        double currentXValue = leftMostXValue + i * increment;
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x + (self.bounds.size.width / PRECISION) * i, 
                            origin.y - [self yValueFromExpression:expression atPosition:currentXValue] * scale);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

This is the error message I get when CGContextStrokePath is called:
`Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.`

**Answer:** I need to put a guard around CGContextAddLineToPoint() to make sure it is drawing within the bounds of the `rect`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= PRECISION; ++i) {
    double currentXValue = leftMostXValue + i * increment;
    double xPoint = self.bounds.origin.x + (self.bounds.size.width / PRECISION) * i;
    double yPoint = origin.y - [self yValueFromExpression:expression atPosition:currentXValue] * scale;
    if (xPoint < (self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width) && xPoint > 0 &&
        yPoint < (self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height) && yPoint > 0) {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xPoint, yPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually means you have a memory problem.

If I had to guess, expressionForGraphView might be returning garbage sometimes.

Comment: The crash is occurring when CGContextStrokePath function is called. I don't understand how it could have anything to do with `expression`.

Comment: Make sure you are only drawing within the bounds of rect.  once you start adding lines to an area outside your context, you might be stomping on some other memory area.  Log your points to verify.

Comment: ah thank you, that explains it. I put a guard around CGContextAddLineToPoint and now it works